# angularjs service that listen to back button

Tags: cordova, angularjs-service

Is there an angularjs service that listens to device backbutton?

I want to listen to device backbutton inside different controllers so i can have access to data within the controller's scope and use it to manipulate the actions once the backbutton is pressed.

Something like the CordovaService

```
notifierApp.service('CordovaService', function($document, $q) {
    var d = $q.defer(),
    resolved = false;

    var self = this;
    this.ready = d.promise;

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        resolved = true;
        d.resolve(window.cordova);
    });

    // Check to make sure we didn't miss the 
    // event (just in case)
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!resolved) {
            if (window.cordova) d.resolve(window.cordova);
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know angular js but you can use backbutton like device rady

```
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

    function onBackKeyDown() {
        // Handle the back button

   }
```

Comment: thanks Flatlineato, i figured out that i should use only one eventListner for backbutton in a single-page app then do different actions depending on what the url/or situation is